# Compile Linux Kernel Module - Cannot build simple kernel module

Tags: module, linux-kernel

I'm trying to compile a kernel module driver but I get the following errors: (the operation generate some files, but not a ".ko" file)

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.16.0-kali7-amd64/build M=/home/z3r0/Scrivania/kernel_modules/start_stop modules
make[1]: ingresso nella directory «/usr/src/linux-headers-5.16.0-kali7-amd64»
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.16.0-kali7-common/scripts/pahole-flags.sh: not found

  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.16.0-kali7-common/Makefile:751: include/config/auto.conf] Errore 1
make[1]: uscita dalla directory «/usr/src/linux-headers-5.16.0-kali7-amd64»
make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Errore 2
```

When I try to execute "make oldconfig && make prepare" I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.16.0-kali7-common/scripts/pahole-flags.sh: not found
  GEN     Makefile
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.16.0-kali7-common/scripts/pahole-flags.sh: not found
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.16.0-kali7-common/scripts/Makefile.build:44: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.16.0-kali7-common/scripts/basic/Makefile: File o directory non esistente
make[1]: ***  Nessuna regola per generare l'obiettivo «/usr/src/linux-headers-5.16.0-kali7-common/scripts/basic/Makefile».  Arresto.
make: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.16.0-kali7-common/Makefile:566: scripts_basic] Errore 2
```

The file is really simple (hello_world.c):

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

static int __init hello_start(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading hello module...\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_end(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye Mr.\n");
}

module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);
```

makefile:

```
obj-m = foo.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Can someone explain where is the error? Thank you

Comment: Kali Linux is actually not very suitable for **learn** Linux kernel programming or anything else: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: Thank you, should I use ubuntu?

Comment: There is a discrepancy in your question. You wrote that the file is called hello_world.c, but the Makefile is building module foo.

Comment: @IanAbbott isn't it the name of the object file it will create?

Comment: If you want the module to be called `foo.ko` and the single source file to be called `hello_world.c`, then you will need the lines `obj-m := foo.o` and `foo-y := hello_world.o`. If you want the module to be called `hello_world.ko` (same base name as the single source file) then you just need the line `obj-m := hello_world.o`.

Comment: Hi. Did you get to fix the issue?

Comment: @Edw590 Hi, I was trying on Kali Debian distro. Now I switched my programming on Ubuntu and using kali only for tools